# Rule that prompts user once but applies results to multiple messages?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to apply an ad-hoc category to a selection of Outlook emails.

I have a VBA script that asks the user for a string and then sets this as the email's category. I run this by moving all emails to be updated to a temp folder, and then run the Outlook rule on all messages in that folder.

```
Public Sub PromptForCat(Email As Outlook.MailItem)
   Category = InputBox("Please enter category to add :")
   Email.Categories = Email.Categories & "," & Category
   Email.Save
End Sub
```

However, this will prompt me for every message in the folder - is there any way to only prompt me once, yet apply the result to all messages in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run the code once for a selected folder you need to iterate over all items in the folder. The `Items` property of the `Folder` class returns an `Items` collection object as a collection of Outlook items in the specified folder:

```
Sub ContactDateCheck() 
  Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
  Dim myContacts As Outlook.Items 
  Dim myItem As Object 

  Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  Set myContacts = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items 
  For Each myItem In myContacts 
    If (myItem.Class = olContact) Then 
      MsgBox myItem.FullName &; ": " &; myItem.LastModificationTime 
    End If 
  Next 
End Sub
```

To get the selected items in Outlook you need to use the `Selection` property of the Explorer class:

```
Sub GetSelectedItems()
  Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
  Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
  Dim MsgTxt As String
  Dim x As Integer

  MsgTxt = "You have selected items from: "
  Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
  Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection
  For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count
    MsgTxt = MsgTxt & myOlSel.Item(x).SenderName & ";"
  Next x
  MsgBox MsgTxt
End Sub
```